# How to change the tty output display in Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux

How can I change my output of the ttys to an other Monitor?

I have plugged in a 1920x1080 Display on HDMI1-0, reported by `xrandr`.
My Laptop-Display is eDP1.

If I now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*n*</kbd>, the output appears on the Laptop Screen, but I want it to be on the HDMI1-0 Display.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Relevant links: <https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5012/tty-on-external-monitor> and <https://askubuntu.com/questions/13248/can-virtual-terminals-ctrlaltf-use-external-monitors>.